# Lagrange multiplier - find maximum of $F(x,y,z) = 2x+y-z$ on the surface: $4x^2 + 2y^2 + z^2 = 40$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

I need someone to walk me through a 3 variable lagrange problem, since I haven't been able to find a reliable source to teach me, please.

Here it is:

Find the maximum of the function $F(x,y,z) = 2x+y-z$ on the surface: $4x^2 + 2y^2 + z^2 = 40$

Comment: is it $2x+y-z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straightforward: your Lagrangian is
$$
L(x,y,z,\lambda) = 2x+y-z -\lambda(4x^2 + 2y^2+z^2 - 40).
$$
Now just write that all the partial derivatives are 0, and you are done:

$$
0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 2-8\lambda x\implies \lambda = \frac 1{4x};
\\
0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 1-4\lambda y\implies \lambda = \frac 1{4y};
\\
0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial z} = -1-2\lambda z\implies \lambda = -\frac 1{2z};
$$

Hence $$z=-2x=-2y.
\\
40 = 4x^2 + 2y^2 + z^2 = 4x^2 + 2x^2 + 4x^2  = 10 x^2;
\\
x=y=2; z=-4\text{ or } x=y=-2; z=4.$$
The maximum is for the first solution ($L$ is bigger).

You can check with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+2x%2By-z+on+4x%5E2%2B2y%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D40).

Comment: the answer is apparently 10 though

Comment: how do you know that? what is 10, the value of the maximum?

Comment: According to the answer key of my midterm review sheet, it's 10. Which I'm guessing is the value of the maximum

Comment: you are right, this is the traditionnal last line error; I made the correction ;)